# Creating a React .JSX React Component

Tags: reactjs

I am getting an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

It has it at line 91 which is the:  "return ( " in the render function.

I don't see anything wrong. Any ideas?

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
var TableExample = React.createClass({  

getInitialState: function () {
    // For testing.
    console.log("In getInitialState.");

    return {  
        Country: []  
    };  
},  

componentDidMount: function () {
    // For testing.
    console.log("In componentDidMount.");

    $.ajax({  
        url: this.props.url,  
        dataType: 'json',  
        success: function(data) {  
            this.setState({  
                Country: data  
            });  
        }.bind(this),  
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {  
            console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());  
        }.bind(this)  
    });  
},  

render: function ()
{
    // For testing.
    console.log("In render.");

    return ( <table> 
    {  
        this.state.Country.map(function (item, key)
        {
            return ( <tr key = { key } > 
                        <td> { item.CountryID } </td> 
                        <td> &nbsp; </td> 
                        <td> { item.CountryName } </td> 
                     </tr>
                   )
        })  
   } </table> );
}

}); 

ReactDOM.render(<TableExample url = "/Home/GetName"/>, 
document.getElementById ('container'));
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You will have to transpile `jsx` to `js` as the browsers do not understand `jsx`. You would have to use `babel` or `typescript` for the transpilation

Comment: That worked...thanks.